# How to know customers who placed next order before delivery/receiving of earlier order? In R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, iteration, rolling-computation

I have a large database having two dates.  E.g. Take superstore data (http://www.tableau.com/sites/default/files/training/global_superstore.zip) 'Orders' Sheet.

One date is let's say date of Order and another is date of shipping/delivery (Assume it is delivery date).  I want to know details of all orders of those customers who placed their next order without waiting for shipping/delivery of any one of their previous orders.

For e.g. Customer with ID 'ZC-21910' placed order with ID CA-2014-133928 on 12 June 2014 which was shipped on 18 June 2014.  The same customer, however, placed next order with ID 'IT-2014-3511710' on 13 June 2014 i.e. before 18 June 2014 (shipping date of one of the earlier orders).

It will be best all such orders (order IDs) are filtered out in a separate dataframe/table.

How can I do it in R?

example dataset

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(customer_id = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", 
"C"), order_id = structure(1:7, .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7"), class = "factor"), order_date = structure(c(17897, 
17901, 17912, 17901, 17902, 17903, 17905), class = "Date"), ship_date = structure(c(17926, 
17906, 17914, 17904, 17904, 17904, 17906), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
df
#>   customer_id order_id order_date  ship_date
#> 1           A        1 2019-01-01 2019-01-30
#> 2           A        2 2019-01-05 2019-01-10
#> 3           A        3 2019-01-16 2019-01-18
#> 4           B        4 2019-01-05 2019-01-08
#> 5           B        5 2019-01-06 2019-01-08
#> 6           C        6 2019-01-07 2019-01-08
#> 7           C        7 2019-01-09 2019-01-10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the advent of dplyr 1.1.0, it is now very easy

```r
df <- structure(list(customer_id = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", 
                               "C"), order_id = structure(1:7, .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
                                                                          "5", "6", "7"), class = "factor"), order_date = structure(c(17897, 
                                                                                                                                      17901, 17912, 17901, 17902, 17903, 17905), class = "Date"), ship_date = structure(c(17926, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          17906, 17914, 17904, 17904, 17904, 17906), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     -7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

df %>% 
  inner_join(df, 
             by = join_by(customer_id == customer_id, 
                          ship_date >= order_date, 
                          order_date <= order_date),
             relationship = 'many-to-many') %>% 
  filter(order_id.x != order_id.y)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 7
#>   customer_id order_id.x order_date.x ship_date.x order_id.y order_date.y
#>   <chr>       <fct>      <date>       <date>      <fct>      <date>      
#> 1 A           1          2019-01-01   2019-01-30  2          2019-01-05  
#> 2 A           1          2019-01-01   2019-01-30  3          2019-01-16  
#> 3 B           4          2019-01-05   2019-01-08  5          2019-01-06  
#> # ℹ 1 more variable: ship_date.y <date>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would structure this workflow in R, note: replicating the functionality in Tableau will be very difficult.

```
# Install pacakges if they are not already installed: necessary_packages => vector
necessary_packages <- c("readxl")

# Create a vector containing the names of any packages needing installation:
# new_pacakges => vector
new_packages <- necessary_packages[!(necessary_packages %in%
                                       installed.packages()[, "Package"])]

# If the vector has more than 0 values, install the new pacakges
# (and their) associated dependencies:
if(length(new_packages) > 0){install.packages(new_packages, dependencies = TRUE)}

# Initialise the packages in the session:
lapply(necessary_packages, require, character.only = TRUE)

# Store a scalar of the link to the data: durl => character scalar
durl <- "http://www.tableau.com/sites/default/files/training/global_superstore.zip"

# Store the path to the temporary directory: tmpdir_path => character scalar
tmpdir_path <- tempdir()

# Store a character scalar denoting the link to the zipped directory
# that is to be created: zip_path => character scalar
zip_path <- paste0(tmpdir_path, "/tableau.zip")

# Store a character scalar denoting the link to the unzipped directory
# that is to be created: unzip_path => character scalar
unzip_path <- paste0(tmpdir_path, "/global_superstore")

# Download the zip file: global_superstore.zip => stdout (zip_path)
download.file(durl, zip_path)

# Unzip the file into the unzip directory: tableau.zip => stdout (global_superstore)
unzip(zipfile = zip_path, exdir = unzip_path)

# Read in the excel file: df => data.frame
df <- read_xls(normalizePath(list.files(unzip_path, full.names = TRUE)))

# Regex the vector names to fit with R convention: names(df) => character vector 
names(df) <- gsub("\\W+", "_", tolower(trimws(names(df), "both")))

# Allocate some memory by creating an empty list the same size as the number of 
# customers: df_list => list
df_list <- vector("list", length(unique(df$customer_id)))

# Split the data.frame into the list by the customer_id: df_list => lis
df_list <- with(df, split(df, customer_id))      

# Sort the data (by date) and test whether or not each customer waited for their 
# order before ordering again: orders_prior_to_delivery => data.frame
orders_prior_to_delivery <- data.frame(do.call("rbind", Map(function(x){
  # Order the data.frame: y => data.frame
  y <- x[order(x$order_date),]
  # Return only the observations where the customer didn't wait: 
  # data.frame => GlobalEnv()
  with(y, y[c(FALSE, 
    apply(data.frame(sapply(order_date[-1], `<`, ship_date[-nrow(y)])), 2, any)),])
}, 
df_list)), row.names = NULL, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Unique customers and orders that were ordered prior to shipping the 
# previous order: cust_orders_prior_to_delivery => data.frame
cust_orders_prior_to_delivery <- 
  unique(orders_prior_to_delivery[,c("order_id", "customer_id")])
```

Comment: When I run this, I get 9952 lines.  When I run your code from your comment to my answer, I get 19819 lines.  When I run the code from my answer, I get 1625 lines.  So clearly the scripts are not equivalent.  To be honest, I don't understand what `with(y, y[c(FALSE, (diff.Date(y$order_date) < diff.Date(y$ship_date))),])` does.  It seems like you're comparing each line with the previous, but an order date that conflicts with a previous ship date is not necessarily conflicting with the row immediately above it.

Comment: please see my revised solution above.

Comment: @MichaelDewar I have revisited the problem and I now think that both yours and my original logic is incorrect.

Comment: Your tidyverse solution gives 48k rows, your base R solution gives 25k rows.  I looked at your revised base R solution in detail.  Your code does not properly handle the fact that the same order can have multiple items (and hence multiple lines) and thus erroneously identifies thousands of extra orders.  For example, Customer ID == "PO-8865", Order ID == "AE-2011-9160".  On the other hand, you miss customer DB-13660's order CA-2014-101077 which conflicts with order US-2014-136497.  The reason you miss it is because you only compare each line's order date with the previous line's ship date.

Comment: @hello_friend perhaps once you have arranged the rows as per order_date you are just comparing a ship date with previous order-date only.  Actually that may not be the case.  Let me show this with help of a dummy data in few minutes.

Comment: You are correct @MichaelDewar about the tidyverse solution, it has been edited. Still I believe you are incorrect about the orders, for each customer a data.frame is created and ordered by the order_date, which is then compared with the previous lines ship date, which is what OPs question is, subsetting records with orders made prior to shipping of the previous order. Your answer is incorrect because it assumes order id must denote uniqueness, but the data is at the product level of granularity, you are dropping an unnecessary amount of information and over-engineering your solution.

Comment: @MichaelDewar in fact OP says: " I want to know details of all orders of those customers who placed their next order without waiting for shipping/delivery of any one of their previous orders."

Comment: You have just dropped all the product information in your first line.

Comment: `library(tidyverse)
a <- c(rep("A",3), rep("B",2), rep("C",2))
b <- c(1:6,6)
c <- as.Date(c("2019-01-01", "2019-01-05", "2019-01-16", "2019-01-05", "2019-01-06", "2019-01-07", "2019-01-09"))
d <- as.Date(c("2019-01-30", "2019-01-10", "2019-01-18", "2019-01-08", "2019-01-08", "2019-01-08", "2019-01-10"))

df <- tibble(customer_id = a, order_id = factor(b), order_date = c, ship_date = d)`
See with this example.  Actually customer A placed two orders while his/her earlier order was open.  If your code is applied, it fetches only only order of A

Comment: @AnilGoyal very true, I apologise, please see edited solution above. I would note that the current accepted solution doesn't work on this data either.[

Comment: @AnilGoyal edited again, the `apply()` function should have been using a Margin = 2

Comment: The OP asked for a vector of all Order IDs.  The code should generate a result that follows from the demands of the business user, not from the granularity of the source data.  If the user wants the item data, they can use my result to filter/join/etc.  However, your code incorrectly identifies Customer ID == "PO-8865", Order ID == "AE-2011-9160".  In fact, this is simply an order with two items, not an order that meets the requirements.

Comment: I would like to thank you @hello_friend.  Your comments have spurred me to find the error in my original solution.  (I have updated above).

Comment: I would like to understand your answer better.  All of the key logic is contained in the line `with(y, y[c(FALSE, apply(data.frame(sapply(order_date[-1], `<`, ship_date[-nrow(y)])), 2, any)),])` which I don't understand.  Could you explain what is happening here?

Comment: @MichaelDewar and you too, your comments did the same for me. `with()` allows for non-standard evaluation to take place so I can use non-quoted and non-prefixed (with data.frame name and "$") variable names. The `sapply()` function takes every order date (except the first), and again uses non-standard evaluation on the `<`, to check whether or not it is less than each ship_date (excluding the last -- this makes each vector the same size for sake of comparison.

Comment: @MichaelDewar we can then convert it to a data.frame and use a column-wise `apply(df, margin = 2, any)` function to check if any ship_date is less than the order date. Because we have dropped the first record, but need a boolean vector to subset `y` the same length as `y` and we know the first record for each customer will not be before a ship_date (it can't be because it's the first record) we combine a FALSE scalar value with the vector of boolean tests `c()`. If you have taken something/learned anything from my solution please feel free to give it an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** My earlier answer did not properly handle the case where Order Date == Ship Date.

I assume that you already loaded your data in an object called `df`.  You can use the first part of @hello_friend's code to get this.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  distinct(`Customer ID`, `Order ID`, `Order Date`, `Ship Date`) %>% 
  arrange(`Customer ID`, `Order Date`, `Ship Date`) %>% 
  mutate(sort_key = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(c(`Order Date`, `Ship Date`), names_to = "Activity", names_pattern = "(.*) Date", values_to = "Date") %>% 
  mutate(Activity = factor(Activity, ordered = TRUE, levels = c("Order", "Ship")), 
         Open = if_else(Activity == "Order", 1, -1)) %>% 
  group_by(`Customer ID`) %>% 
  arrange(Date, sort_key, Activity, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(Open = cumsum(Open)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  filter(Open > 1, Activity == "Order") %>% 
  select(`Customer ID`, `Order ID`)
```

First, take only distinct order and customer IDs, otherwise the multiple items from the same order will confuse things and cause an incorrect result.  Then, pivot the data so that each order become two rows, each representing a distinct activity: either ordering or shipping.  We create a running total of the number of open orders.  You're looking for when this becomes two or more.

I use an ordered factor for Activity to make sure that I always open an order before closing it.  This matters when the order date and ship date are the same.

I use a special sort_key column to make sure that I close out the old order before opening a new one, in the cases when the customer orders on the same day that something else was shipped.  You may want the reverse logic.

All of this assumes that a given Customer ID and Order ID only appear once in the data, which actually isn't true in your dataset, as you can see with:

```
df %>% group_by(`Customer ID`, `Order ID`) %>% filter(n_distinct(`Ship Date`)> 1) %>% select(1:9)
```

Comment: Hi Michael nice solution (+1), how about: `res <- 
  df %>% 
  rename_all(~str_replace(str_trim(str_to_lower(names(df))), "\\W+", "_")) %>% 
  group_by(customer_id) %>% 
  arrange(order_date) %>% 
  filter(cumsum(c(0, diff.Date(order_date))) < cumsum(c(0, diff.Date(ship_date)))) %>% 
  ungroup()`

Comment: Thanks it worked 
In Last line I filtered for Orderdates only and I got what I wanted.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to filter for the orders

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if you included the expected output. Interpreting your question and example data, it sounds like the following rows should be returned:

```r
#>   customer_id order_id order_date  ship_date
#> 1           A        1 2019-01-01 2019-01-30
#> 2           A        2 2019-01-05 2019-01-10     <---
#> 3           A        3 2019-01-16 2019-01-18
#> 4           B        4 2019-01-05 2019-01-08
#> 5           B        5 2019-01-06 2019-01-08     <---
#> 6           C        6 2019-01-07 2019-01-08     
#> 7           C        7 2019-01-09 2019-01-10
```

As currently stated it is essentially a cumulative window question, which can be accomplished using `purrr::map_vec()` in conjunction with `dplyr::row_number()`:

```r
df |>
  arrange(customer_id, order_date, ship_date) |>
  group_by(customer_id) |>
  filter(
    order_date < map_vec(row_number(), function(n)
      min(ship_date[1:n], na.rm = TRUE)),
    order_date > min(order_date)
  ) |>
  ungroup()

#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>   customer_id order_id order_date ship_date 
#>   <chr>       <fct>    <date>     <date>    
#> 1 A           2        2019-01-05 2019-01-10
#> 2 B           5        2019-01-06 2019-01-08
```

For large datasets, you can probably achieve a more efficient solution using the [`slider`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=slider) package.